# Audit file modifications over ssh in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, tty, audit

I wanted to monitor all the modifications made to file in Linux server

On some research I found audit tool which I have installed and configured using following commands

```
yum install audit # installation
/etc/init.d/auditd start # started service
auditctl -w /root/file-name -p war -k password-file # configured rule to audit file 
ausearch -f /root/file-name # Command to search modifications
```

It has recorded all the modifications made to the specific file

Every thing was good until I came across following

**Case 1 :** I have deleted file which i am monitoring using audit from the server using following command

```
rm -rf /root/file-name
```

It was recorded as following


`type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1540222267.321:1057): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=7ffe22abf91a a1=941 a2=1b6 a3=7ffe22abed70 items=2 ppid=21053 pid=42458 auid=14628 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=5 comm="touch" exe="/bin/rm" key="password-file"`

**Case 2 :** I have deleted file from a remote server using following command

```
ssh cl14470 "echo 'rm -rf /root/chaithu'|sudo su - root"
```

It was recorded as following


`type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1540222588.196:1118): arch=c000003e syscall=263 success=yes exit=0 a0=ffffffffffffff9c a1=ce70c0 a2=0 a3=7fff52a6af40 items=2 ppid=42520 pid=42533 auid=14628 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=9 comm="rm" exe="/bin/rm" key="password-file"`

Now point which confuses me is why tty is recorded as none when I executed command remotely

I have searched over web regarding this but unfortunately I was not able to find any thing which clears my confusion

Could some one explain me why it was recorded as tty=(none) in case 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's how to command was executed -- without any controlling tty.

You haven't passed any `-t` option to `ssh`, and `ssh` does not allocate a pseudo-terminal by default when it is called with arguments, as in your case. (`ssh cl14470 "echo ..."`).

This is the default behavior as described in the `ssh(1)` manpage:

> When the user's identity has been accepted by the server, the server
>        either **executes the given command in a non-interactive session** or, if no
>        command has been specified, logs into the machine and gives the user a
>        normal shell as an interactive session.  All communication with the
>        remote command or shell will be automatically encrypted.
>
> **If an interactive session is requested** ssh by default will only request a
>   pseudo-terminal (pty) for interactive sessions when the client has one.
>   The flags -T and -t can be used to override this behaviour.

So `ssh` will only allocate a pseudo-terminal on the *remote* machine by default if **a)** it is run with no 'command' argument(s) **and b)** the stdin of the ssh client on the *local* machine is a tty.

The `-t` option is forcing `ssh` to allocate a pseudo-tty, and the `-T` option is forcing it to **not** allocate one, irrespective of other factors.